# Can a less or sass file be minified

Tags: css, sass, less

Can I minify a less of sass file, means to remove spaces/linebreaks etc from less file and will it compile correctly to css files afterwards?

Comment: it seems you'd want to minify it after it was compiled to CSS

Comment: Why do you want to do that? As long as you don't let the sass/less file by parsed client side, you want to have it as verbose/readable as possible. The sass and less compiler have an option to minimize the generated code.

Comment: I want to read sass files and parse their data into objects. I ask this question because I want to know if I can count on the fact that those files should have line breaks between elements or not.

Comment: If you want to know such things you should be more clear about this. So your question is not if you can minify such files, because your initial purpose is to parse such files. And you should be clearer about if you mean `.sass` and/or `.scss` files (or their corresponding equivalents in less) because they have different rules about syntax.

Comment: OK. thanks t.niese. I want to parse scss and less files and wanted to know what are the rules I can count on for doing that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you'd want to do that, but it shouldn't be a problem.

I normally use [Prepros](http://alphapixels.com/prepros/) to compile my Sass files to CSS, it easily allows me to minify the result at the same time.

You don't gain anything by minifying the source (Sass/LESS) files, it just makes them harder to read. Unless of course, you're serving them directly to the visitors (letting the client side compile them using some javascript code) but if you're concerned about performance I wouldn't recommend that approach.